# nginx: redirect all SSL subdomain to main SSL domain; got "not private" error

Tags: ssl, redirect, nginx

All subdomains (both http and https) should redirect to the main SSL domain. It's easy for http to https but not for http AND https to https.

If I try `http://foobar.domain.tld` it's redirected to `https://foobar.domain.tld` with error `Your connection is not private`. It should be `https://domain.tld`. For special subdomains like `mail` and `www` there exists a letsencrypt cert and the redirect works fine, but not for `foobar`.

How can I avoid the cert check for the https redirect and why is the http-to-https redirect a double step (first to https subdomain then to the main https)?

Target:

```
http://domain.tld -> https://domain.tld
http://*.domain.tld -> https://domain.tld
https://domain.tld -> https://domain.tld
https://*.domain.tld -> https://domain.tld
```

My nginx block:

```
server {
  server_name domain.tld *.domain.tld;
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  return 301 https://domain.tld$request_uri;
  # rewrite ^/(.*) https://domain.tld/$1 permanent;
}  

server{
  server_name *.domain.tld; 
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  return 301 https://domain.tld$request_uri;
}

server {
  server_name domain.tld;
  listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.tld/privkey.pem;
  include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

  root /var/www/domain.tld/html;

  index index.html index.htm;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }

  location ~ /.well-known {
    allow all;
  }
}
```

results:

```
http://domain.tld -> https://domain.tld (works)
https://domain.tld -> https://domain.tld (works)

http://mail.domain.tld -> https://domain.tld (works)  # has own cert
https://mail.domain.tld -> https://domain.tld (works)  # has own cert

http://foobar.domain.tld -> https://foobar.domain.tld (cert error)  # has no cert
https://foobar.domain.tld (cert error)  # has no cert
```

**Update 1:**

Thanks to the comment by Richard Smith, I could get the http to https part working, but not https subdomain to https main domain. Here is my ssl-params.conf:

```
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";
ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_tickets off;
ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;
resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
resolver_timeout 5s;
# removing of the following row solves the http-subdomain-to-https-domain problem
# add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains";
add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
```

Comment: Are you using HTTP Strict Transport Security?

Comment: Hmm, that solved the part for `http://*.domain.tld -> https://domain.tld` but not the `https://*.domain.tld -> https://domain.tld`. I'll add my ssl-params.conf in the question.

Comment: If you do not have a cert for foobar (or a wild card cert), https redirect will always result in an error. The secure connection is always negotiated before `nginx` can process the request.

Comment: Oh, ok, not what I wanted to hear.

Comment: maybe you mean a SNI-preread http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_ssl_preread_module.html#ssl_preread